# Changing background color of Psychtoolbox fixation point

Tags: matlab, screen, psychtoolbox

I took some code posted on a [Yahoo help forum](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/psychtoolbox/conversations/topics/9532) and wanted to know how I can modify it to have a grey background on the fixation point. Apologies I am completely new to Psychtoolbox.

```
screenNum=0;
[window, rect] = Screen('OpenWindow', screenNum, 1);
[X,Y] = RectCenter(rect);
FixCross = [X-1,Y-40,X+1,Y+40;X-40,Y-1,X+40,Y+1];
Screen('FillRect', window, [255,255,255], FixCross');
Screen('Flip', window);
WaitSecs(2)
sca
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added 'Screen('FillRect', window, [192,192,192]' and it did the job

```
screenNum=0;
[window, rect] = Screen('OpenWindow', screenNum, 1);
[X,Y] = RectCenter(rect);
FixCross = [X-1,Y-40,X+1,Y+40;X-40,Y-1,X+40,Y+1];
Screen('FillRect', window, [192,192,192])
Screen('FillRect', window, [255,255,255], FixCross');
Screen('Flip', window);
WaitSecs(2)
sca
```